# Why does template.php override not work?

Tags: theming

I'm trying to get links from the PDFPreview module to open in a new tab. As described in [this issue](https://drupal.org/node/1876236), overriding the formatter function in template.php does not work.  One can modify the function in the actual .module file, but this is obviously not good practice.  Why does it not work?

Code from the module:

```
/**
 * Theming functions for our formatters
 *
 * @todo Clearify the image cache thing...
 * @todo Let user choose what preview image to show on non-PDF files
 */
function theme_pdfpreview_formatter($variables) {
  $img_tag = '';
  $item = $variables['item'];

  $image = array(
    'title' => $item['description'],
    'uri' => $item['preview'],
  'alt' => $item['description'],
  );

  $element =array();
  $element['item'] = $image;
  $element['image_style'] = $variables['settings']['image_style'];
  switch ($variables['settings']['image_link']) {
    case 'file':
      $element['path'] = array(
        'path' => file_create_url($item['uri']),
        'options' => array(),
      );
      break;
      case 'content':
      $element['path'] = array(
        'path' => $variables['entity_type'] . '/' . $variables['entity']->nid,
        'options' => array(),
      );
      break;
  }
  $img_tag = theme('image_formatter', $element);
  $wrapper_tag = $variables['settings']['tag'];
  $description = $variables['settings']['show_description'] ? '<' . $wrapper_tag . ' class="pdfpreview-description">' . $item['description'] . '</' . $wrapper_tag . '>' : '' ;
  return sprintf(
          '<div class="pdfpreview pdfpreview-%s" id="pdfpreview-%s">'
          . ' <%s class="pdfpreview-image-wrapper">%s</%s>'
          . ' %s'
          . '</div>',
          $variables['instance']['field_name'],
          $item['fid'],
          $wrapper_tag, $img_tag, $wrapper_tag,
          $description
  );
}
```

Code from template.php:

```
/**
 * Theming functions for our formatters
 *
 * @todo Clearify the image cache thing...
 * @todo Let user choose what preview image to show on non-PDF files
 */
function my_theme_pdfpreview_formatter($variables) {
  $img_tag = '';
  $item = $variables['item'];

  $image = array(
    'title' => $item['description'],
    'uri' => $item['preview'],
  'alt' => $item['description'],
  );

  $element =array();
  $element['item'] = $image;
  $element['image_style'] = $variables['settings']['image_style'];
  switch ($variables['settings']['image_link']) {
    case 'file':
      $element['path'] = array(
        'path' => file_create_url($item['uri']),
        'options' => array('attributes' => array('target' => '_blank')),
      );
      break;
      case 'content':
      $element['path'] = array(
        'path' => $variables['entity_type'] . '/' . $variables['entity']->nid,
        'options' => array(),
      );
      break;
  }
  $img_tag = theme('image_formatter', $element);
  $wrapper_tag = $variables['settings']['tag'];
  $description = $variables['settings']['show_description'] ? '<' . $wrapper_tag . ' class="pdfpreview-description">' . $item['description'] . '</' . $wrapper_tag . '>' : '' ;
  return sprintf(
          '<div class="pdfpreview pdfpreview-%s" id="pdfpreview-%s">'
          . ' <%s class="pdfpreview-image-wrapper">%s</%s>'
          . ' %s'
          . '</div>',
          $variables['instance']['field_name'],
          $item['fid'],
          $wrapper_tag, $img_tag, $wrapper_tag,
          $description
  );
}
```

Comment: please paste the function (or link to) from the module that you would like to override.

Comment: And the actual code you are using as the override.

Comment: Updated. My theme is named `my_theme`. I have tried calling the function `my_theme_pdfpreview_formatter` and `my_theme_theme_pdfpreview_formatter`.  Neither seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `my_theme_pdfpreview`, because even though there's a specific function assigned to it in `hook_theme()`, you should use the key to override.

I admit I got confused as well at first :)

Comment: Did you actually get this function to work with PDFPreview?

Comment: Yep, I did. Worked fine

Answer (score 0):

To override a theme function like this one `theme_pdfpreview_formatter()`.

- Replace the word `theme` with you theme name `my_theme`. It should
  look like this `my_theme_pdfpreview_formatter()`.
- Avoid using underscore for theme names (it's known for causing
  problems). Ideally your theme would be called `mytheme`, the function
  would be `mytheme_pdfpreview_formatter()`
- Make sure you're editing the correct `template.php` file.
- Clear Cache after adding the new function.

Comment: The template.php file is in the base folder of my theme. Is there another location that might be overriding?

Comment: You got it in the right place.

Comment: Hmmm... maybe it's the underscore/theme name, then.  I'll have to experiment with another theme name.